# How can I check all processes that are executed simultaneously when an app begins, in Android?

Tags: android

I have a question about Android system.
What is that is there any way to see , when an app begins, all processes which are executed simultaneously?

For example, I can see 2 processes, com.android.chrome:privileged_process1 and com.android.chrome:sandboxed_process3 for Chrome, by using "adb logcat | grep 'Start proc'":

```
nickeys@nickeys-linux-machine:~/kernel/msm/arch/arm64/boot$ adb logcat | grep 'Start proc'
    02-10 19:23:38.387  1077  1088 I ActivityManager: Start proc 9889:com.android.chrome:privileged_process1/u0a57 for service com.android.chrome/org.chromium.content.app.PrivilegedProcessService1
    02-10 19:23:38.410  1077  2211 I ActivityManager: Start proc 9902:com.android.chrome:sandboxed_process3/u0i3 for service com.android.chrome/org.chromium.content.app.SandboxedProcessService3
```

Because if the member process is already on the memory(RAM) when I type the command, I will not see the logcat log('Start proc').
So I need to find another way.

I'm waiting for any clue which I can do it.

Sincerely,

Comment: I cannot understand why some words in my writings have been disappeared.... originally, there is "Hello, experts." but after I submit it, there left only "experts."

Comment: answer to the comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/search?q=greeting

Comment: @Selvin oh... I'm a newbie on stackoverflow so, I did not notice it. Thanks a lot